# Implementing copy-on-write buffer with mmap on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, mmap, copy-on-write

I've been playing around with copy-on-write buffers on Linux and the following example seems to work as intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 4096

#define SHM_NAME "foobar"

int main(void)
{
    int fd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    int r = ftruncate(fd, SIZE);

    char *buf1 = mmap(NULL, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                     MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    strcpy(buf1, "Original buffer");

    char *buf2 = mmap(NULL, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                      MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

    // At this point buf2 is aliased to buf1

    // Now modifying buf2 should trigger copy-on-write)...

    strcpy(buf2, "Modified buffer");

    // buf1 and buf2 are now two separate buffers

    strcpy(buf1, "Modified original buffer");

    // clean up

    r = munmap(buf2, SIZE);
    printf("munmap(buf2): %i\n", r);
    r = munmap(buf1, SIZE);
    printf("munmap(buf1): %i\n", r);
    r = shm_unlink(SHM_NAME);
    printf("shm_unlink: %i\n", r);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However under OS X (10.10) the second `mmap` call returns `MAP_FAILED`, with `errno` = 22 (`EINVAL`). The [OS X man page for `mmap`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html) seems to suggest that this should work (it even mentions copy-on-write in the description of the `MAP_PRIVATE` flag), and I've experimented with various different flags for the calls to `mmap`, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas ?

Comment: On `OS X` using `MAP_PRIVATE` doesn't handle file descriptors the same.

Comment: @l'L'l: thanks for the hint - can you give me any more details ?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/256a83cad3dd43895553).

Comment: Thanks - but it doesn't look like you're passing `offset` to `mmap` in that example ?

Comment: OK - thanks - I'll have a play. I'm not sure it's going to help though as I'm trying to get a `MAP_PRIVATE` buffer which is initially aliased to a `MAP_SHARED` buffer and then gets remapped via copy-on-write. So I think `offset` will need to be 0 for both, but I'm prepared to try anything. ;-)

Comment: [Here's one](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/208f5ed903b09f7e8571) using `open`; It does seem that using `shm_open` and doing the alias with `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` somehow messes with the file descriptor. It could be a bug from the looks of it.

Comment: Thanks - that looks more promising - I hadn't thought of trying a regular file - I'll give it a try...

Comment: Awesome - I just tried `open` with a regular file instead of `shm_open` and everything works now ! Many thanks for your help - feel free to write this up as an answer if you like, and I'll up-vote/accept it, otherwise I'll do it myself later for anyone else who might have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that using `shm_open` with `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` does something undesirable with the file descriptor. Using `open` is a possible workaround:

```
int fd = open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
...
```

Result:

```
munmap(buf2): 0
munmap(buf1): 0
shm_unlink: -1
```

Using `shm_open` with `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_PRIVATE` results in an `Invalid file descriptor`, although using it with `MAP_SHARED` and `MAP_SHARED` for example does not. It's unclear to me whether this is a bug, or by design - the behavior does not seem correct though.

Comment: Thank you - switching from `shm_open` to `open` with a regular file solved my problem!